# Setup ubuntu 18.04 repository on hard drive

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, hard-drive, repository

I have installed xubuntu 18.04 in my laptop.
I have copied the repositories of ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop's hard drive.

How can I set my ubuntu system to access this repository on my hard drive?
How can I set my sources.list file for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 18.04's repositories are upgrading constantly with new security patches and bugfixes. If your laptop connects to a network, exclusive use of older packages will soon leave your system vulnerable to published exploits.

Comment: It makes sense mirroring repositories (and keeping them updated) to a local server in a network with many computers and having them use the local repositories instead of many hundreds or more of individual connections to download the same updates. Big companies do that also for Windows updates. Having the full contents copied to a local drive and not updated makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I agree with both, but I need to have the repository on my hard drive. I do not have an stable connection to access a repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do this:

REPO PATH SAMPLE:  /opt/ubuntu
SOURCES LIST CONTENT: (in /etc/sources.list)

```
deb file:/opt/ubuntu/ bionic main multiverse restricted universe
deb file:/opt/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main multiverse restricted universe 
deb file:/opt/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main multiverse restricted universe 
deb file:/opt/ubuntu/ bionic-security main multiverse restricted universe 
deb file:/opt/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main multiverse restricted universe
```

If your repo is x64 only, then use this format

```
deb [arch=amd64] file:/opt/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main multiverse restricted universe
.......
```